# How can I find and extract an image from inside a proprietary file format?

Tags: jpeg, tiff

I have cached preview files from Capture One (a photo processing program, similar to Lightroom) where I have lost the originals. Capture One saves previews in their proprietary .cop format and I'm not sure how to go about identifying what's what in there.

There are the strings `ETIFFTagInteropIFD` and `JPEG Embedded TIFF Tags` seen in the HEX view which suggests that they are somehow embedding a TIFF in there.

I do have original JPEG files with their corresponding COP-file, but when comparing them there isn't much that's similar - which makes sense I guess, since the preview COP-file is roughly half the size of the original.

What conclusions can I draw from this and what are some good tools for going further?